# Unity - Error building APK

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am very new to the Unity and I am trying solve the problem for 1 week but still can't solve and I decided come here to ask expert.
During build apk in Unity I got below error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[

]
stdout[

]
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String[] progress_strings, Single progress_value, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.CompileResources (System.String stagingArea, System.String packageName, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries androidLibraries)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal (System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Please anyone can tell me what the problem is? and how to solve this error?

Appreciate for your kindly help.

Comment: Hard to tell anything without stderr and stdout details. Try uninstall/reinstall java+android sdk (and ensure everything work properly!) and try a build, or if this doesn't work, roll back to an older (android)sdk version until you get error details

Comment: I think this might be build issue with android SDK build version 24 as I have seen many complaints regarding that. Most people seem to have deleted v24 and used older build tools to build apk.

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1239
and 
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/commandinvokationfailure-failed-to-re-package-resources-no-error.411752/

check this and confirm about this issue... i hope this helps

Comment: Dear Mark, thanks for ur reply, I also wondering why  stderr and stdout was not generated any log. Okay, let me try to uninstall unity and install a new one. Anyway, thanks you so much.